# Библиотека необходимых классов С#

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Добрый день! Я тут подумал, а что если написать одну библиотеку где будет все необходимое, но тут возник вопрос. Так как я не опытный специалист еще, а только учусь, меня интересует большая библиотека не будет ухудшать оптимизацию или будет?

Comment: `где будет все необходимое` - необходимое для кого?

Comment: Ну в принципе я думаю стараться сделать так, чтобы там было все необходимое для других начинающих разработчиков.

Comment: Такая библиотека называется .NET Framework

Comment: Да я знаю, но я имел в виду в одной библиотеке будут разные виды сортировки, списки, стек, и так далее. И да я знаю что есть уже готовые реализованы классы списков, стеков и так далее, но это все в разных библиотеках

Comment: Ты не можешь знать, что понадобиться человеку, а что нет. У всех цели разные и направления разные. Поэтому это как-то бессмысленно ориентироваться на абстракцию О_о

Comment: Если либа не имеет зависимостей, то можно пихать все в кучу. Как вот JonSkeet.MiscUtil А вот если зависимости от других частных библиотек, то для них лучше отдельные либы делать, чтобы не пришлось включать в проект то, что там не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размер .NET dll-ки никак не влияет на производительность/оптимизацию. Когда JIT компилирует IL инструкции в машинний код, все имена методов/полей/свойств/классов превращаются в указатели. Доступ по указателю занимает некоторое константное время.